# Pandas: Generating a data frame from each spreadsheet in a large excel file

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe, spreadsheet, jupyter

I have a large excel file which I have imported into pandas, made up of 92 sheets.

I want to use a loop or some tool to generate dataframes from the data in each spreadsheet (one dataframe from each spreadsheet), which also automatically names each dataframe.

I have only just started using pandas and jupyter so I am not very experienced at all.

This is the code I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import datetime
%matplotlib inline

concdata = pd.ExcelFile('Documents/Research Project/Data-Ana/11July-27Dec.xlsx')
```

I also have a list of all the spreadsheet names:

```
#concdata.sheet_names
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making each DataFrame its own variable you can assign each sheet a name in a Python dictionary like so:

```
dfs = {}
for sheet in concdata.sheet_names:
    dfs[sheet] = concdata.parse(sheet)
```

And then access each DataFrame with the sheet name:

```
dfs['sheet_name_here']
```

Doing it this way allows you to have [amortised O(1) lookup](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed) of sheets.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: what syntax would I use to plot the data from a dataframe when calling it as dfs['sheet_name_here'] ?

I've tried to call it like a normal dataframe but it doesn't seem to work:

     plt.scatter((dfs['1107']['Date&Time']),((dfs['1107']['Concentration'])))

Comment: @MichaelDrakonakis: that looks ok. What do you mean by it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: the prompt responds 
'TypeError: invalid type promotion'

Where should I look at editing to change this issue?

Comment: Oh try this: `plt.scatter(x=dfs['1107']['Date&Time'].values,y=dfs['1107']['Concen‌​tration'].values)`

Comment: @MichaelDrakonakis: by the way, maybe you should ask a new question since this is quite a different task than what you set out to do above.